# How do I mask an arrays elements that aren't present in a second array in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, filtering, masking

This is what I currently have:

```
x = range(10)
x2 = array(x)
y = [3,6,8]

for i in range(len(x)):
     x2[i] = x2[i] in y

x = ma.masked_where(x2 == False, x)
```

This gets me what I want, but I want to do so without looping.
Any way to mask the array x where the values aren't present in y?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This approach using list comprehension doesn't rely on any numpy constructs. It keeps the number if it's in `y`, and puts a `-` in if it's not

```
x = [i if i in y else '-' for i in range(10)]
```

output

```
['-', '-', '-', 3, '-', '-', 6, '-', 8, '-']
```

Change the '-' if you want to change the default for the mask.

Comment: This seems to be exactly what I want, but I need to be able to mask this array and apply that mask to another array, and then eventually compress them both. Know any way to mask this? I've tried masked_where and attempted to use the type as a flag, and I've tried masked_value to specify the '-' but none seem to work.

Comment: Wait I got it! I just changed the '-' to float('nan') and used masked_invalid. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use set.intersection to get the matching numbers, it will return you the values that match, and it is done without looping:

```
x = range(10)
y = [3,6,8]
s1 = set(x)
s2 = set(y)
s1.intersection(s2)

(Output:) set([8, 3, 6])

x = [1,2,3,4,5]
y = [2,3,6,7,8]
s1 = set(x)
s2 = set(y)
s1.intersection(s2)

(Output:) set([2, 3])
```

You can get a list by casting the set:

```
y = list(s1.intersection(s2))
```

Comment: This is useful, but I need the masked array as an output because I then need to apply that mask to another array. Unless you know a way to produce an array that only keeps the elements corresponding to the indexes from the array intersection?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `numpy` to do the loops for you, therefore accelerating the calculations.

```
x = np.arange(10)
y = np.array([3,6,8])

mask = np.all( x!=y[:,None], 0 )
x = np.ma.masked_where(mask,x)
```

Comment: This is definitely a good backup. Ideally I wouldn't loop at all, but this is likely what I'll have to do. Thanks!